# Multiplying a ring(or an ideal) by an element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ideals

I was looking at a proof of the statement: Given a ring $R$ and an ideal $M$, $R/M$ is a field$\iff$M is maximal.

The backwards direction (assume $M$ maximal) proof involved a statement where we take an $r\in R$ such that $r\notin M$ and take $M + r*R$ which is an ideal as $M$ and $R$ are ideals, which implies that this construction must be $R$ itself.

I had two questions about this statement. First of all, I realized very quickly that for a given ring $r*R\neq R$. Is this simply because $R$ is not a group under $*$, i.e., if $R$ were a field, would $r*R=R$, or is there something else going on? If it's because of the group assumption, what would the reasoning behind a proof be (I assume something to do with existence and uniqueness of inverses but not 100% sure)?

The second was assuming that $r*R$ is an ideal. By definition of an ideal I know $r*R\in R$, but by the above question there's no guarantee that $r*R=R$. How then do we know that $r*R$ is an ideal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $aR$ is an ideal because for $r,r^\prime\in R,x\in aR$ we have $ar+ar^\prime=a(r+r^\prime)\in aR$ and $(ar)b=a(rb)\in aR$ (the proof for left ideals is similar).

We don't necessarily expect $r\cdot R$ to be equal to $R$, in fact, if it is then the ideal is trivial. It is precisely when $r\cdot R\neq R$ that things begin to become interesting. Fields, because every (nonzero) element is invertible, do not have any interesting ideals.

Comment: I agree that fields don't have interesting ideals, but strictly speaking every nonzero element of a field is invertible, not every element, so we have the zero ideal in addition to the unit ideal.

Comment: I guess that part of my question may have been poorly worded. I was wondering more in general as to the conditions of a group/ring/some algebraic structure such that that structure would be invariant under multiplication(or addition, depending on operation) by one of its elements. For example, if we have a group $G$, and an element $g\in G$, then would $g*G=G$? Some quick examples seem that way (i.e. $Z/n$ under addition), but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's become from definition directly, $r*R \ \& \ R*r$ are right and left ideals generated by $r$, respectively.